# Xgboost : How to make a one CSV to one label in Dmatrix

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

I tried to use `xgboost` to build a regression model.

Today, each of my inputs is a 2-D array, and each input has a corresponding one value.

However, I had a problem converting data into Dmatrix.

X_data_train is a 3d array (`# shape(num_files, length,width)`) while label_data_train is a 2d array (`# shape(num_files,1)`).

The following error message will appear:

> **ValueError: Input numpy. Ndarray must be 2 dimensional**

At present, I can only use a file temporarily and convert it into a two-dimensional array.

However, when the program continues, the following error message will appear:

> **Check failed: preds.Size() = info. Labels_.Size() (100 vs. 1) labels are not correctly provided**

But I do only have one label. How can I fix those error messages??

```
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import plot_importance
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as npnter code here

mms = MinMaxScaler()

#dataset
files_num_train = 5
files_num_test  = 2

#for train
x_data_train = []
label_data_train = []
read_y_data_train = pd.read_csv('path/label.csv')
y_data_train = read_y_data_train['Label'].to_numpy()

#for test
x_data_test = []
label_data_test = []
read_y_data_test = pd.read_csv('path/label.csv')
y_data_test = read_y_data_test['Label'].to_numpy()

#training set
for i in range(files_num_train):
    read_x_data_train = pd.read_csv('path/train%s.csv'%i,index_col = 0).to_numpy()
    x_data_stc_train = mms.fit_transform(read_x_data_train)
    x_data_train.append(x_data_stc_train)
    label_data_train.append(y_data_train[i])

#testing set
for j in range(files_num_test):
    read_x_data_test = pd.read_csv('path/test%s.csv'%j,index_col = 0).to_numpy()
    x_data_stc_test = mms.transform(read_x_data_test)
    x_data_test.append(x_data_stc_test)
    label_data_test.append(y_data_test[j])

x_data_train = np.array(x_data_train)
label_data_train = np.array(label_data_train)
label_data_train = label_data_train.reshape((files_num_train,1,1))
print(x_data_train)#shape = (files_num_train,100,100)
print(label_data_train)#shape = (files_num_train,1,1)

params = {
    'booster': 'gbtree',
    'objective': 'reg:gamma',
    'gamma': 0.1,
    'max_depth': 5,
    'lambda': 3,
    'subsample': 0.7,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.7,
    'min_child_weight': 3,
    'silent': 1,
    'eta': 0.1,
    'seed': 1000,
    'nthread': 4,
}
#dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_data_train, label_data_train)
#will appear: ValueError: Input numpy.ndarray must be 2 dimensional

#temporarly use one file to train
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_data_train[0], label_data_train[0])
num_rounds = 300
plst = params.items()
model = xgb.train(plst, dtrain, num_rounds)
#appear error message here:
#Check failed: preds.Size() == info.labels_.Size() (4000 vs. 1) labels are not correctly provided

x_data_test = np.array(x_data_test)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(x_data_test)
ans = model.predict(dtest)

plot_importance(model)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but I'll write a solution to this question for viewers.

I guess you need to reshape your explanatory variable in your code like below.

Suppose, X is an explanatory variable, and data is DataFrame object using Pandas,

```
self.data_x_value = self.data['X'].values.reshape(len(self.data['X']), 1)
```

Thanks,